# Is there a general definition of the white noise?

Tags: white-noise

In my course, a white noise over G is defined as a bounded linear operator $\xi$ from the Hilbert space $G$, to $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ such that $\xi(g)$ is a normal variable with mean 0 and variance $||g||^2$, and $Cov(\xi(g_1), \xi(g_2))=<g_1,g_2>$

Comment: It's any random signal with constant power spectral density: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise

Comment: OP's definition is as abstracted out from experience and intuition as possible

Comment: There is no question in the text.  The question in the title appears to be answered by the definition in the text.  Thus, there seems to be nothing to answer.